# How do I write this in OpenCV with Python?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, code-translation

How do I write the following MATLAB piece of code in Python by using OpenCV ? I have problems with the last line of code, I don't know how to implement that 'single' function. Can you help me ? Thanks.

```
img = imread('');
grayImage = rgb2gray(img);
kernel1 = -1 * ones(3)/9;
kernel1(2,2) = 8/9
filteredImage = imfilter(single(grayImage), kernel1);
```

My code looks as following, what I tried so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('', 0);

kernel1 = np.ones((3,3), np.float32)/9
kernel1[1][1] = 0.8888889

filteredImage = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel1)
```

Comment: you could probably use `img.astype(np.float32)` to convert the numpy array to single-precision floating point type

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. The entire image gets white with only some black dots on it.

Comment: that depends on how you're displaying the image afterwards, you might need to rescale it to [0.0,1.0] range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the MATLAB version:

```matlab
img = rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png'));

kernel = -ones(3)/9;
kernel(2,2) = 8/9;

out = imfilter(single(img), kernel1);
imshow(out, [])  % <-- note automatic image rescaling
```

[image: matlab]

Here is the python version:

```python
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("peppers.png", 0)

kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.float32) / -9.0
kernel[1][1] = 8.0/9.0

out = cv2.filter2D(img.astype(np.float32), -1, kernel)
out = (out - out.min()) / (out.max() - out.min())

cv2.imshow("image", out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: python_opencv]

Comment: It worked, thank you so much ! My mistake was that I forgot to put that minus sign at the kernel.